# iOS: how to make nav title align left when back button is hidden

Tags: ios

I've followed this code to implement a title and subtitle in the navigation bar: [iPhone Title and Subtitle in Navigation Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817181/iphone-title-and-subtitle-in-navigation-bar)
which works really well.  However, I have a section where I've hidden the back button by doing:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

and I'd like the title to take up the extra room on the left where the button used to be.

Is this possible?

Comment: did you find out solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

Set the origin of navigationItem.titleView

For example

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if (self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton) {
        CGRect frame = self.navigationItem.titleView.frame;
        frame.origin.x = 10;
        self.navigationItem.titleView.frame = frame;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the view in question is the initial view this doesn't seem to work?